# How to get number of affected row in Android's Room

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I want to delete data inside a database using room `@Query annotation` with `DELETE` command. How do I check whether the data has been deleted or not? I tried to search for `@Query` return type but couldn't get the answer.

Comment: Show the code you've written

Comment: `A @Delete method can optionally return an int value indicating the number of rows that were deleted successfully.` https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data